# Custom font title for UIButton

Tags: iphone, uibutton

Is there a way to have custom fonts to the title of a button.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The `UIButton` class exposes a [titleLabel](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW40) property, upon which you can change things like the font, the text color, etc.

Comment: Note some properties of `titleLabel` are reset after `setTitle()`.

Comment: Its not recommended to set textColor property of the titleLable according to Apple's documentation "Do not use the label object to set the text color or the shadow color. Instead, use the setTitleColor:forState: and setTitleShadowColor:forState: methods of this class to make those changes." https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIButton/titleLabel

Answer (score 22):

Set the font of the button's `titleLabel`:

```
myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Courier" size:22.0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always render text in a `UIImage` and then configure the button to use that with `setImage:forState:`. This allows you to do custom fonts, labels with icons, images, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to list all available fonts and then select your font, run  this Swift code:

```
UIFont.familyNames().forEach {
    print($0)
    UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName($0).forEach {
        print("  \($0)")
    }
}
```

It prints all font names for their font families. Then assign the same font name as printed.

```
button.titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 20.0)
```