# How to change all UIButton fonts to custom font?

Tags: iphone, xcode, fonts, interface-builder

Is there any way to do this?
I want to have a custom font that I've downloaded to show on ever UIButton.

Comment: LMGTFY :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242361/custom-font-title-for-uibutton

Comment: But how to change all fonts for all buttons at once?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use  `IBOutletCollection` then this should be direct.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutletCollection(UIButton) NSArray *buttons;
```

Connect the buttons to this outlet collection and later alter the font in a single shot using,

```
[self setValue:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:30] forKeyPath:@"buttons.font"];
```

Comment: Technically, they are different fonts. The first argument will have to change. In `Helvetica`'s case, it will be `Helvetica-Bold`. It is mostly predictable but isn't guaranteed. Take a look at the font names [`here`](http://iosfonts.com/).

Comment: What if you don't use IBOutletCollection?

Answer (score 5):

One way you could do it is to subclass UIButton setup your desired font and use your subclass instead of UIButton.

**Edit**

```
//
//  MyUIButton.h
//

@interface MyUIButton : UIButton {

}
+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType;
@end

//
//  MyUIButton.m
//


#import "MyUIButton.h"


@implementation MyUIButton

+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType{
   UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:buttonType];
   [[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
   return button;
}

@end

Then just use it like this:

[MyUIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]
```

The other thing you can try is writing a category for UIButton and overriding it there.

**Edit2**

```
    //
    //  UIButton+Font.h
    //

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface UIButton (DefaultFontExtension)
+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType;
@end


    //
    //  UIButton+Font.m
    //

#import "UIButton+Font.h"

@implementation UIButton (DefaultFontExtension)

+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType{
       UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:buttonType];
       [[button titleLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:12]];
       return button;
    }

@end
```

Now just import "UIButton+Font.h" it will override the default UIButton settings.

Comment: This would work, but will force you to replace all your UIButtons or add another method. So, regardless you will have to go through and make changes.

Comment: If you will use a category you will only have to import your category header file

Comment: Nice.  I guess this is the least cumbersome way.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815

```
button.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];
```

Apple's documentation is quite good.  Try looking it up there first, then search SO, then search Google, then write a question. :)

**Edit:**
Well, the easiest way is to replace any `fontWithName` parameters with a constant, such as a macro.

```
#define BUTTON_FONT_NAME @"Helevetica"
```

If you haven't done that, then you will have to replace them all.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but is there a way to change all fonts in all buttons at once?

Comment: I think you misunderstood me :)

I want to know if there is avoid this:
[code]
button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]
button2.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]
button3.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]
[/code]

So I don't have to change one by one, is there any way to set the default font for all UIButtons?

Comment: @Wikiboo: Just stuff it in a subclass and just set your custom class of all your UIButtons to that subclass.  Edit: Just like Patrick said.

Answer (score 0):

A possible option is to use a subclass, then edit the init.

```
//MYButton.m
-(id) initWithTitle: (NSString *)title {
    self.titleLabel = title;
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: FONT_NAME size FONT_SIZE];
}
```

Then just make all of your UIButtons MYButtons instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *NameBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    NameBtn=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    [NameBtn setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [NameBtn setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NSString *textb=[[self.searchList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
    CGSize constraintb = CGSizeMake(310 ,10);
    CGSize sizeb = [textb sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:constraintb lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [NameBtn setTitle:textb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    NameBtn.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size: 12.0];
    NameBtn.frame = CGRectMake(85, 12, MAX(sizeb.width ,3.0f),12);
    [NameBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    NameBtn.tag=indexPath.row;

    [cell addSubview:NameBtn];
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: 
[self.btnTopics.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"System" size:12]];